# automate comparison of source records to Records in destination after migration

Tags: automated-testing

Excel file which is Source file. this file will be migrated to multiple tables.
I need to compare Source file to destination after migration. This process of comparison should be automated...Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What kind of tables? In what kind of application, webbased or desktop? Maybe you can give more context with exact details, now its to sparse to answer. Guess my initial confusiong

Comment: Raj I think we need to put this on hold for right now. What process do you have right now? What tables does it get migrated to, and how does it happen? How do you extract the information after? What does automation in this context mean to you? Once you've edited this information in (as well as Niel's question) we can open this back up for answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I feel like there should be better tools out there to do exactly what you want but I don't know of any..

What I would probably end up doing is to create a DB-connection from Excel to your 3 tables (Top Menu->Data->From Other Sources). This gives you access to the "migrated" data from within Excel.

You can then compare column-by-column with the source Excel data.

To keep it clean and tidy you can separate each table and source data in it's own sheet and use any Excel compare tools.

I've personally used Florencesoft's tool successfully:
https://www.florencesoft.com/excel-diff/

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used ExcelCompare from https://github.com/na-ka-na/ExcelCompare

Its a command-line tool which you can give two excel files/sheets and it will compare everything and print out difference with cell/cords and the difference in text.

You should be able to parse its text output in a continuous integration environment to check automatically if the new version of the Excel output is correct.

Example output:

```
> excel_cmp xxx.xlsx yyy.xlsx
DIFF  Cell at     Sheet1!A1 => 'a' v/s 'aa'
EXTRA Cell in WB1 Sheet1!B1 => 'cc'
DIFF  Cell at     Sheet1!D4 => '4.0' v/s '14.0'
EXTRA Cell in WB2 Sheet1!J10 => 'j'
EXTRA Cell in WB1 Sheet1!K11 => 'k'
```

Comment: Hi , the situation here is, comparison is easy if two excel sheets are mapped one to one, but what if source is one file and destination is spread into 3 diff tables??

Comment: Ah, guess I didnt understand your question. Its not tables in Excel...